# how can i set blowfish for CRYPT_BLOWFISH function in php

Tags: encryption, set, bit, salt, blowfish

i use this code for encrypt my data to blwofish but i dont know really to convert to blowfish or other encryption.

`echo crypt('ab','$2a$09$anexamplestringforsalt$')."\n
";` 

and i'm try bottom code but it's false

`echo CRYPT_BLOWFISH('ab','$2a$09$anexamplestringforsalt$')."\n
";`

Answer (score 0):

It is the crypt parameter string, that defines which algorithm is used:

```
$2a : This describes the algorithm (BCrypt) but should be 2y nowadays
$09 : This is the number of rounds and is usually 10 or higher
$anexamplestringforsalt : This should be a really random salt of a given alphabet
```

To generate a BCrypt hash, it is much safer to use the new [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function though, there exists also a [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) for earlier PHP versions.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```